# How to know which bank will keep my data safer? (Europe, single country)

Tags: banking, bank-account, european-union, security, europe

I was looking at four banks in one country, which are based in France, Belgium and 2 in Austria, and I was looking for something that would make me choose one over the other... So I thought what's important for me, and it is privacy and my private data security.

So how do I choose a bank like this, how do I know the truth about their data protection and privacy policy? How do I find out the details that nobody would tell or even know if I was to ask at the bank?

I am of course looking at the branches, since I mentioned they are all are just in one country, so I am also wondering - does it even matter where the bank is based if I would be signing up just for its branch that is in another European country?

I am European citizen myself, so I would like to focus this question for European citizens.

Please edit the question if there's something wrong with it - I seem to ask questions in a wrong way for this website often, hah. :-)

Comment: If you mean privacy - from the governments?  Or from them (example) accidentally releasing your data to the public>

Comment: I mean from absolutely anybody. I know I won't get full privacy, but I want as much privacy as possible from anything. Mainly processing it for building profiles, selling to third-parties, giving away to someone who does build profiles, etc..

Comment: that's tough.  Austria has a tradition of "banking privacy", so maybe there's a slight advantage.  :/

Comment: @Fattie I've heard of that, yes. I feel like the French might also be good at it, and Belgian perhaps. But that's just a feeling. I know it's a tough question, which is why I couldn't answer it on my own... :/

Comment: France == unfortunately not, no.  For sure, they are the bottom of that list!

Comment: "_How do I find out the details **that nobody would tell or even know**_" If the bold part is true, the answer to the first past is "You can't"!

Comment: Seems on-topic here, but you may find more detailed responses at security.stackexchange.com [not 100% certain this would be considered on-topic there, but I believe it would].

Comment: Before you can make security decisions, you need a threat model. What breaches of your data are you concerned about, to whom and with what consequences? Security is about trade-offs, not about perfection, and you have to know what your priorities are.

Comment: @MikeScott My priority is that as little information about me as a person would be collected and tied together or even accessible to anyone at all. I'm simply uncomfortable with the idea.

Comment: @Jack In that case, don’t have a bank account at all. That’s the way to minimise the information that anyone has about you. If that’s not acceptable, you have to be less absolute about your requirement.

Comment: Surely you should be considering a Swiss bank if this is so important to you?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banking_in_Switzerland#Banking_secrecy

Answer (score 1):

The EU has pretty good regulation on personal data and privacy. So there's a respectable floor to seriously how any of these four banks have to take the issue.

> how do I know the truth about their data protection and privacy policy?

I'm sure they publish the policy somewhere. How well it is adhered to is another matter, and something you can probably only find out by getting one of their IT staff to break confidentiality. If you can't do that, it's probably a good sign.

Comment: Haha, so I guess it's impossible to choose a bank based on the things I wrote, and the only thing I can go on is lowest rates?

Comment: But what about the branches? What do they operate according to?